# JoinTable in JPA for 3 different entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create a join table with `@JoinTable` from 3 different entities. Below is the code sample I'm using. While creating join table I'm getting below error. Please help to resolve.

There are 3 entities in my design. Credential, Category and Tenant. 
Now I'm trying to make a join table that will contain the pk of these 3 tables using @ManyToMany annotation between them. Below is the relationship which I'm trying to make.

[image]

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "CREDENTIALS")

    public class CredentialsEntity {

        /** The credential id. */
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private int credentialId;   

        @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
        @JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_HAS_CREDENTIALS",
                joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(table="CATEGORY", name = "CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"),
                @JoinColumn(table ="TENANT", name = "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(table="CREDENTIALS", name = "CREDENTIAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
        private List<TenantEntity> tenantEntities;
    }
```

==========================

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TENANT")

    public class TenantEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private int tenantId;

         @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tenantEntities", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
         private List<CredentialsEntity> credentialsEntities;
}
```

==========================

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class NodeCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int categoryId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
    private List<CredentialsEntity> credentialsEntities;
}
```

Caused by:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Cannot find the expected secondary
>   table: no TENANT available for
>   com.aricent.aricloud.entity.CredentialsEntity     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getJoin(Ejb3Column.java:363)     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.getTable(Ejb3Column.java:342)    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.checkPropertyConsistency(Ejb3Column.java:584)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.buildCollectionKey(CollectionBinder.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1336)

---

**EDIT**

I'm able to do the jointable like below, as mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509579/hibernate-how-to-join-three-3-tables-in-one-join-table-in-annotation)

is this correct approach or I'm doing something wrong?

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_HAS_CREDENTIALS",
            joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "CREDENTIAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(table = "CATEGORY", name = "CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
            @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName ="ID")
            @ElementCollection
            private Map<TenantEntity, NodeCategory> tenantCategoryMap = new HashMap<TenantEntity, NodeCategory>();
```

Comment: How come that `CredentialsEntity` has both @ManyToOne and @ManyToMany association with `TenantEntity` at the same time? Am I missing something?

Comment: `@ManyToOne` - join column in Credentials table for Tenant. `@ManyToMany` - to put the TenantEntity pk in new join table. 
The issue is in join table I cant pass table TENANT

Comment: errm, how does NodeCategory relate to CredentialsEntity.tenantEntities ?

Comment: @Neil - there is no direct relation between NodeCategory and CredentialsEntity.tenantEntities. But NodeCategory table does have a OneToMany relation with TenantEntity directly.

Comment: Simple answer : you CANNOT do that.

Comment: are you saying we cannot have join table for 3 different entities ?

Comment: you CANNOT do that. Can't get clearer. You have Credentials and Tenant relation yet no category present ... so it cannot insert something when it has no category!

Comment: I'm able to do this, please check the edit section. My concern is, will it create any issue while trying to insert values with Map in JoinTable ?