# ManyToManyToMany - Joining three tables with Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

At first I thought [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509579/hibernate-how-to-join-three-3-tables-in-one-join-table-in-annotation) might solve my problem:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @JoinTable(name = "user_permission",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<Project, Permission> permissions = new HashMap<>();

}

@Entity
public class Project {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Permission {
    ...
}
```

But in this implementation there can only be one `Permission` set per `Project`. I'd like to accomplish the ability to set multiple permissions for a project such that the following could be true:

```
| user_id | project_id | permission_id |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 1       | 1          | 1             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 1       | 1          | 2             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 1       | 2          | 1             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 1       | 2          | 2             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 2       | 1          | 1             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 2       | 1          | 2             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 2       | 2          | 1             |
|---------|------------|---------------|
| 2       | 2          | 2             |
```

Comment: If the key/value of a Map are entities then that is not an ElementCollection; it needs ManyToMany as per the JPA spec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an entity dedicated to your relation table. It's the way we declare relations with their own attributes for instance.
This would result in the following implementation:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PermissionAssignation.class)
public class PermissionAssignation {

     @Id
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
     private User user;

     @Id
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="project_id")
     private Project project;

     @Id
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="permission_id")
     private Permission permission;
     ...
}
```

I used the solution found in this post: [Hibernate and no PK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767277/1429387)

It explains how to create the PK with field (I did not test it).
If it does not work, you'd better use a `EmbeddedId` class.

And if you want your relation to be bidirectional, you can then use a `Set<PermissionAssignation>` (or `List`, as you prefer/need):

```
 @Entity
 public class User {

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
      private Set<PermissionAssignation> permissions;

 }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Only thing I added was a list of projects to the user to help me navigate through the permissions. Having the project in the list will allow the user to "view" the project, and the permissions will allow them to take various actions on the project.

Comment: This is great answer, not something everyone will use but I loved this solution. Can you share example of embedded id. Is there any more improved version of this in spring jpa?

Comment: If you use a CrudRepository to access this class, you'll need to use it both for the class and PK, right?  `CrudRepository<PermissionAssignation, PermissionAssignation>`

Comment: How to add a PermissionAssignation? I got error ConversionNotSupportedException

Answer (score 0):

Since I recently ran into this and still struggled, I wanted to share a [complete code example](https://pastebin.com/8Z7ju9u6).  This example uses a separate `@EmbeddedId` class which will still create a table with 3 PK/FK columns.  My example makes use of Lombok to fill in a bunch of boiler-plate code such as getters/setters, constructors, etc.  It was also necessary to override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods. This was written using Spring framework, which wires up the repos & tests. Hopefully someone finds this a useful guide.

```
/* ENTITY CLASSES */
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "_Who")
public class Who {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "who", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    List<WhoWhatWhere> storage;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "_What")
public class What {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String thing;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "_Where")
public class Where {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String place;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "_WhoWhatWhere")
public class WhoWhatWhere {
    public WhoWhatWhere(Who who, What what, Where where) {
        this.who = who;
        this.what = what;
        this.where = where;
        this.setId(new WhoWhatWhereId(who.getId(), what.getId(), where.getId()));
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    WhoWhatWhereId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "who_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Who who;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "what_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private What what;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "where_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Where where;
}

@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class WhoWhatWhereId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "who_id")
    Long whoId;
    @Column(name = "what_id")
    Long whatId;
    @Column(name = "where_id")
    Long whereId;
}

/* REPOSITORIES */
@Repository
public interface WhoRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Who, Long> {
    Iterable<Who> findWhoByName (String name);
}
@Repository
public interface WhatRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<What, Long> {
}
@Repository
public interface WhereRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Where, Long> {
}
@Repository
public interface WhoWhatWhereRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<WhoWhatWhere, WhoWhatWhereId> {
}

/* TEST CLASS */
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class ThreeWayAssocTest {

    private final WhoRepository whoRepository;
    private final WhatRepository whatRepository;
    private final WhereRepository whereRepository;
    private final WhoWhatWhereRepository whoWhatWhereRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ThreeWayAssocTest(WhoRepository whoRepository, WhatRepository whatRepository, WhereRepository whereRepository, WhoWhatWhereRepository whoWhatWhereRepository) {
        this.whoRepository = whoRepository;
        this.whatRepository = whatRepository;
        this.whereRepository = whereRepository;
        this.whoWhatWhereRepository = whoWhatWhereRepository;
    }

    @Test
    public void attemptPersistence() {
        /*
        * the commented pieces can be used to do the initial inserts.  Later, fetch existing values so as not to fill
        * up the database
        */
        Who who =
        /*        new Who();
        who.setName("Carl");
        whoRepository.save(who);*/
                whoRepository.findById(1L).get();
        What what =
        /*        new What();
        what.setThing("strawberry");
        whatRepository.save(what);
        what.setThing("salad");
        whatRepository.save(what);*/
                whatRepository.findById(2L).get();
        Where where =
        /*        new Where();
        where.setPlace("plate");
        whereRepository.save(where);*/
                whereRepository.findById(1L).get();
        WhoWhatWhere whoWhatWhere = new WhoWhatWhere(who, what, where);
        whoWhatWhereRepository.save(whoWhatWhere);
        LOGGER.debug("finished");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSerializing() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Iterable<Who> examples = whoRepository.findWhoByName("Carl");
        Who carl = examples.iterator().next();
        LOGGER.debug("Carl: {}", carl);
        LOGGER.debug("found some: \n {}", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(examples));
    }
}
```