# Spring Data JPA - create @Composite key for the three tables

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, composite-primary-key, jpa-2.2

I am extending my question from here: [Define CompositeKey with three tables using JPA/Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57307609/define-compositekey-with-three-tables-using-jpa-hibernate). In this example, I am looking to create **Composite key** to create unique combination of PRODUCT_ID, CATEGORY_ID, STOCK_ID.

I developed below code, but not sure on how to save the records into DB.

Stock.java

```
@Entity
public class Stock implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer stockId;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String stockCode;

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String stockName;

    // Owner of the relationship
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "linkPk.stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<StockCategoryProductLink> stockCategoryProductLinks = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(Integer stockId, String stockCode, String stockName,
            Set<StockCategoryProductLink> stockCategoryProductLinks) {
        super();
        this.stockId = stockId;
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.stockCategoryProductLinks = stockCategoryProductLinks;
    }

    public Integer getStockId() {
        return stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    public String getStockCode() {
        return stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    public String getStockName() {
        return stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public Set<StockCategoryProductLink> getStockCategoryProductLinks() {
        return stockCategoryProductLinks;
    }

    public void setStockCategoryProductLinks(Set<StockCategoryProductLink> stockCategoryProductLinks) {
        this.stockCategoryProductLinks = stockCategoryProductLinks;
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String productCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "linkPk.product", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    private List<StockCategoryProductLink> userDepartmentRoleLinks;

    public Product(String productName, String productCode) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public List<StockCategoryProductLink> getUserDepartmentRoleLinks() {
        return userDepartmentRoleLinks;
    }

    public void setUserDepartmentRoleLinks(List<StockCategoryProductLink> userDepartmentRoleLinks) {
        this.userDepartmentRoleLinks = userDepartmentRoleLinks;
    }
}
```

Category.java

```
Entity
@Table(name = "category", catalog = "mkyongdb")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "[DESC]", nullable = false)
    private String desc;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "linkPk.category")
    private Set<StockCategoryProductLink> stockCategories = new HashSet<>(0);

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name, String desc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Category(String name, String desc, Set<StockCategoryProductLink> stockCategories) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.stockCategories = stockCategories;
    }

    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Set<StockCategoryProductLink> getStockCategories() {
        return stockCategories;
    }

    public void setStockCategories(Set<StockCategoryProductLink> stockCategories) {
        this.stockCategories = stockCategories;
    }

}
```

StockCategoryProductLink.java

```
@Embeddable
public class StockCategoryProductLink implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private StockCategoryProductLinkId linkPk = new StockCategoryProductLinkId();

    @Transient
    public Stock getStock() {
        return getLinkPk().getStock();
    }

    @Transient
    public Category getCategory() {
        return getLinkPk().getCategory();
    }

    @Transient
    public Product getProduct() {
        return getLinkPk().getProduct();
    }


    public StockCategoryProductLinkId getLinkPk() {
        return linkPk;
    }

    public void setLinkPk(StockCategoryProductLinkId linkPk) {
        this.linkPk = linkPk;
    }
}
```

StockCategoryProductLinkId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class StockCategoryProductLinkId {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID")
    private Stock stock;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private Product product;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Stock getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

ManyToManyApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ManyToManyApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ManyToManyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    @Autowired
    private StockRepository stockRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        saveDataFirstTime();

    }


    private void saveDataFirstTime() {
        // Category
        Category category1 = new Category("CONSUMER", "CONSUMER COMPANY");
        categoryRepository.save(category1);

        // Product
        Product product = new Product("Product-1", "AB");
        productRepository.save(product);

        // Stock
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("PADINI");

        // StockCategoryProductLink
        StockCategoryProductLink link = new StockCategoryProductLink();
        link.getLinkPk().setCategory(category1);
        link.getLinkPk().setProduct(product);
        link.getLinkPk().setStock(stock);

        stock.getStockCategoryProductLinks().add(link);

        stockRepository.save(stock);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.entity.Stock.stockCategoryProductLinks[com.example.entity.StockCategoryProductLink]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ManyToManyApplication.main(ManyToManyApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.example.entity.Stock.stockCategoryProductLinks[com.example.entity.StockCategoryProductLink]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:736) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1664) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I know what you said, but I don't think it's what you meant. You said

> Actually I've three tables, Stock, Category and Product. `@ManyToMany` relationship between Stock and Category, as well as `@ManyToMany` relationship between Category and Product.

It helps to think about this abstractly. In Chen notation what you said is

[image: Stock System Diagram 1]

However this is probably not what you meant. This is problematic because you will need a new `Category` entity for every `Stock` and `Product` relationship. So, if you have a category of ETF then it will be duplicated for every stock in BobsBestETFs product, in fact for every instantiated relation.

What you meant is probably more along the lines of a `Stock` and `Product` relationship with a `Category` attribute, like so.

[image: Stock Product Diagram 2]

This this allows for many products each with many stocks and a specific category attribute for each product/stock relation. The issue you will have with this is that you don't want `Category` to be an attribute but rather a lookup table of categories, like so:

[image: Stock Product Diagram 3]

And I think this is what you are looking for. This should be fairly simple to implement with a composite ID but the examples you are showing seem to be somewhat out of date or unclear. Better to find better examples. This is how I would model the last schema.

```
@Entity
public class Stock {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
@Entity
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
@Entity
@Data
public class StockProduct {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StockProductPk id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    private Product product;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("stockId")
    private Stock stock;

    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
}
@Embeddable
@Data
public class StockProductPk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long stockId;
    private Long productId;
}
```

And as an example to use it:

```
private void create() {
    Category catEtf = new Category();
    categoryRepo.save(catEtf);
    Stock s1 = new Stock();
    stockRepo.save(s1);
    Product bobEtfs = new Product();
    productRepo.save(bobEtfs);

    // create a relationship
    StockProduct bs1 = new StockProduct();
    bs1.setId(new StockProductPk());
    bs1.setProduct(bobEtfs);
    bs1.setStock(s1);
    bs1.setCategory(catEtf);
    stockProductRepo.save(bs1); 
}
private void read() {
    StockProduct sp1 = new StockProduct();
    Product p1 = new Product();
    p1.setId(1L);
    sp1.setProduct(p1);
    List<StockProduct> bobEtfs = stockProductRepo.findAll(Example.of(sp1, ExampleMatcher.matching()));
    System.out.println(bobEtfs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Perfect, How can we give name to constraints `alter table stock_product_category add constraint FK2vtbnakkg59skleh35oebx3lk foreign key (category_category_id) references category (category_id)`

Comment: I think that's the `ForeignKey` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way if we can apply through constraints, if I dont want to use composite key ? Have raise new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352521/spring-data-jpa-how-to-apply-constraint-for-the-case-of-three-tables-having-man

Comment: @K. Nicholas - I don't wanted to use CategoryId, Instead I wanted to use CategoryName, Could you please let me know how we can tweak this ?